# why my passwords in json file is in long numbers not in characters

Tags: java, arrays, json, eclipse, passwords

Hye. I do not know why the Json file data is in very long numbers . I did google on how to read or to convert but i cant find it . 
the code :

```
public static String characters[]  ={"a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"};
    static Set<String> honeyWordSet = new HashSet<String>();
    public static void generateHoneywords()
    {
        Random rn = new Random();
        StringBuffer word = null;
        while(honeyWordSet.size()<101)
        {
            word = new StringBuffer("");
            int numOfChar = 0;
            do
            {
                numOfChar = rn.nextInt(10);
            }while(numOfChar<1);

            for(int j=0;j<numOfChar;j++)
            {
                word.append(characters[rn.nextInt(characters.length)]);
            }
            honeyWordSet.add(word.toString());

        }
        try
        {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(
                    new File("jsonFiles\\honeyWord.json"),
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    });
            for(Object obj : honeyWordSet)
            {
                map.put(obj.toString(), "");
            }
            mapper.writeValue(new File("jsonFiles\\honeyWord.json"), map);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this the password of only 11 characters and when it is in json file , it become this long and i do not know how to read or convert it into characters . do the honeywords even successful ?

```
{
    "password":
        {"1":"70682930466663424031633987195811742589048303033286246995265263751152227528040",
        "2":"88802133142308152475235386639891850783867613742545017627734579091864714529274",
        "3":"77044523958204133748269546403028532501526864842254089627589521382689534716884",
        "4":"113492302589409959817526131876347993996825827444440850435946334757636904815969",
        "5":"91634880152443617534842621287039938041581081254914058002978601050179556493499",
        "6":"41789555638182490504480050404782832255306254702785469397392735598495731403077",
        "7":"77192224159977635473426980559151056575052583226217544606649626090165685301539",
        "8":"107763495085302273747458393013408732609403066244716270716686466222930271749415",
        "9":"51946338038242917578331882905973383336531776777297488598702974224296580020506",
        "10":"85110112177512606543858375459297335339239818511701266034254858362091911608971",
        "11":"73269189142166684209325577062514786983019191154169834309660168458666001346810",
        "12":"73156569697674755343634566103724041451079384421332857450856494193159381684698",
        "13":"108991649772298152043643302386517965908573452354267517199577281734443595966514",
        "14":"103218584326081094673548050085606147092617983259240563762028264068035877000891",
        "15":"35640613886241200026418217328422061636534287249966444867910277776917351260845",
        "16":"77192224159977635473426980559151056575052583226217544606649626090165685301539",
        "17":"20553885541631119247001227156676802314981306735372789521402284493774173915265",
        "18":"50243977471952517172155509992929227707259745184556108795150213914029337799858",
        "19":"85201461088932565530158869031891990127412955203087590241988738533258350146502"},
    "index":8
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code, with en empty json file, and it gives me that JSON: {"dfrde":"","kusf":"","shqv":"","jbqdwv":"","neal":"","gkv":"","sxipc":"","xogiczabf":"","mmvvu":"","ip":"","pff":"","unhcd":"","duhbqjl":"","leptzw":"","lcssxuz":"","rs":"","qubr":"","gocopk":"","gtsdyga":"","jm":"","oyupu":"","js":"","dacol":"","oiyc":"","cksel":"","xor":"","wxviuvy":"","a":"","b":"","c":"","e":"","octedocrc":"","buzuba":"","i":"","j":"","eivgxqkk":"","ipwbsicdz":"","jewwf":"","q":"","txt":"", ........ } What JSON are you expecting? and what is initially in your json file?

Comment: The code is in the signup page . i create a Honeywords(it able whenever user is created their password will make honeyword generated . it will reshuffle between the characters in the password and create honeyword ) and the json file is a honeyword one of the users password. @Bentaye

Comment: what do you mean by "the code is in the signup page"? This is very unclear. All I can see is that when I run the code you put in your question, it does not produce the json you posted.

Comment: Oh . I am sorry . What i meant is when i run my application and then try to register a user the json file produced that result . The output is just the long numbers . I run my code in eclipse . The json file that i posted here is the result after i register a user and use this code https://github.com/shabnam701/HoneyWords/blob/master/Honeywords%20-Making%20Password%20Cracking%20Detectable/src/common_interface/Honeyword.java